# FORTRAN INQUIRE statement and FLEN parameter

Tags: file-io, fortran, fortran90

Apparently, some versions of FORTRAN allow a parameter FLEN in the INQUIRE statement.  Pretty useful thing, it will give the size of the file in question in bytes.  But, AFAICT, this is pretty new.  Anyone know how standard this is in FORTRAN now?  Generally speaking, how recent does your FORTRAN have to be have this feature?  I am particularly interested in PGI and gfortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLEN is not a standard specifier for INQUIRE, but SIZE is as of Fortran 2003.

If the file storage unit of the processor is a byte (which is what is recommended, and common), then the variable specified with SIZE will be defined with length of the file in bytes.

Comment: Thanks.  Would appreciate your wisdom on a follow up question coming soon.